# Is there any way to log XML or JSON in one line in WSO2 Microintegrator

Tags: logging, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

This is the log output in the console in Integration Studio

```
2022-11-17 16:32:05 DEBUG Service: - To: /services/Service, WSAction:XYS Direction: request, Request = ======== Log Request =======, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ><soapenv:Body>
      <Read>
         <filter>
            <Field>XYS</Field>
         </filter>
      </Read>
   </soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

I didn't find any out-of-the-box solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways you can achieve this without writing any code.

**Option 01: Global Solution**

Update your `CARBON_CONSOLE` and `CARBON_LOGFILE` appenders in `<MI_HOME>/conf/log4j2.properties` to something like the ones below.

```
# CARBON_CONSOLE is set to be a ConsoleAppender using a PatternLayout.
appender.CARBON_CONSOLE.type = Console
appender.CARBON_CONSOLE.name = CARBON_CONSOLE
appender.CARBON_CONSOLE.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.CARBON_CONSOLE.layout.pattern = [%d] %5p {%c{1}} - %replace{%msg}{[\r\n]+}{}%ex%n
appender.CARBON_CONSOLE.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
appender.CARBON_CONSOLE.filter.threshold.level = DEBUG
```

```
# CARBON_LOGFILE is set to be a DailyRollingFileAppender using a PatternLayout.
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.type = RollingFile
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.name = CARBON_LOGFILE
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.fileName = ${sys:carbon.home}/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.filePattern = ${sys:carbon.home}/repository/logs/wso2carbon-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.layout.pattern = [%d] %5p {%c} - %replace{%msg}{[\r\n]+}{}%ex%n
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.policies.type = Policies
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.strategy.max = 20
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.filter.threshold.level = DEBUG
```

If you just want to update the console log just update the `CONSOLE` appender. Remember this will remove all the new lines from all log messages, not just the messages from the `Log Mediator`, also this will not affect any stack-trace logs, etc. So I don't really see any issue using this approach.

**Option 02: Log Mediator-Specific Solution**

When you are logging do not rely on the Log level full to log the Payload, instead simply Log the message body as seperate property. While logging replace the newline characters. In the below example, I'm using XPATH 2.0 replace function for this. So if you have not enabled XPATH 2.0 in Micro Integrator add the following to the `deployment.toml`.

```ini
[mediation]
synapse.enable_xpath_dom_failover="true"
```

Then in your `Log Mediator` use something like the below.

```xml
 <log level="custom">
     <property name="MESSAGE_BODY" expression="fn:replace($ctx:body, '\n', '')" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" />
 </log>
```

Comment: Option1 didn't work for me. But Option2 did work.

Comment: @Mitja glad it worked. I did test both approaches and both should work.